# Azure WebJob not writing to output

Tags: c#, azure, output, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure WebJob that was writing to the output when I debugged it locally, but doesn't when I run it in Azure.  The Output blob container is completely empty and the output window in the `scm.azurewebsites.net` site is greyed out and blank.  Do I need to set anything up to get my output to be sent there?

Here is a screenshot of what they both look like:

[image: Webjob no output]

Here is the code I'm running on the Webjob:

```
public static void InsertSQLData([BlobTrigger("blobcontainer/{name}")] Stream input, string name)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    RetryAbleBCP rtbcp = new RetryAbleBCP(input,
         "dbo.FullText",
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection"].ConnectionString,
        SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, 
        ',', 
        500, 
        null);
    try
    {
        rtbcp.BulkInsertCSV();
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryException eoom)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eoom.Message);
    }
    catch (IOException eio)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eio.Message);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException eiop)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Row {0}: {1}", rtbcp.NumRowsRead, eiop.Message));
    }
    catch (SqlException se)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("General Application Exception: {0}", e.Message));
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Finished Batch Insert.  Elapsed: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);           
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you are writing logs using `Console.WriteLine()`. To have the output show up in the WebJobs dashboard, use `TextWriter`, like so:

```
public static void InsertSQLData([BlobTrigger("blobcontainer/{name}")] Stream input,
                                 string name, TextWriter log)
{
    // ...
    log.WriteLine("some message");
}
```

Comment: In addition to what Pranav asked: are you setting the right connection strings?

Comment: Console.WriteLine().  And I am setting the right connection strings because the container (azure-jobs-host-output) was created by the webjob and the actual job is executed correctly.  I just don't get the output

Comment: I just found the TextWriter.  That was it!  Thanks for the heads up!